# Wordpress admin plugin to save hidden input data to database

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a Wordpress plugin for the admin area. It needs to set options and write to a file and database based on the options that are saved.

I have tried creating a "Create File" button which sends `POST` data back to itself. I now need to create a file and add a column to the database based on a hidden boolean filed.

I'm struggling because I can't do what I want because the form needs to have a different action. Any advice on how to so this?

Comment: Improved grammar and made the question clearer

Comment: still can't understand what he wants :)

Comment: I explained it well in the original question, but looking at it now, I realize not many of you will understand. I have a set of options based on which I want to create a file in the wordpress installation directory. I found a way in the meantime to do what I want, using different approach. In the original one, though, I wanted to have an hidden input field in my plugin settings page, that will let the system know all the settings fields are populated, and based on that, I would create a file once the script was loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a different action? Without any code examples that show what you're doing and what exactly is not working, we only can imagine and give you general info. In Wordpress, you don't have to care about naked url options cause the core will do this for you. Its enough to register the required hooks, read the passed data here and do what is required with them. Simple storing settings wouldn't require to extend the database scheme, since Wordpress already have a table for this. You could use the Wordpress functions here.

See the article of the Wordpress developers page: https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages

Using the hooks, its no big deal to create a file too. Simple write your PHP code after saving the settings in the database. How you concretely do this depends on the requirements: Is the data passed as form field? Is it fetched from an external source (like api)? Depending on the requirements this should be done with relatively less work using a search engine, cause enough sample codes exists for those scenarios.